# What's the difference between Object.entries and Object.keys?

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between `Object.entries` and `Object.keys`? In which case should I use one or the other one?

Comment: One gives you only the *keys* the other one the keys *and values*. You'd use one when you want only the keys, the other if you want the keys and values. Not sure what is unclear about this.

Comment: The difference can pretty easily be seen by reading documentation on the methods: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Ah SO. This question is well worded, easy to understand, and helpful, yet still closed with downvotes...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns only the own property names and works for ES5.

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array of arrays with key and value and works from ES6.

If you need only keys or like to filter the keys, then take `Object.keys`, otherwise `Object.entries`.

Comment: `Object.keys` is really old and works from the stone age until now.

Answer (score 15):

`Object.keys(obj)` – returns an array of keys.

`Object.entries(obj)` – returns an array of [key, value] pairs.

Consider the below example.

```
 let user = {
 name: "John",
 age: 30
};
```

`Object.keys(user) = ["name", "age"]`

`Object.entries(user) = [ ["name","John"], ["age",30] ]`

When you want a `key, value` pair, you would use `Object.entries`.
When you just want the `key`, you would use `Object.keys`.

Answer (score 3):

`Object.keys` gives you an array of the keys in that object. where as `Object.entries` returns an array of arrays containing key value pair.

```js
const object = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 };
console.log(Object.keys(object));
console.log(Object.entries(object));
```

Answer (score 3):

Both methods are used to iterate over Objects in JavaScript. The difference is:

**Object.Keys ->** will return an array of keys of objects.

**Object.entries ->** will return an array of arrays, where each array contains key and its value.

Note: - Objects in JavaScript include arrays and strings too.

Let’s understand behaviour of both methods with examples:

**Example with an object literal:**

```
const obj = {
   firstName : 'Kane',
   lastName : 'Williamson'
}

// Object.keys(obj) will give you:
[ 'firstName', 'lastname' ]

// Object.entries(obj) will give you:
[ [ 'firstName ', 'Kane' ], [ 'lastName ', 'Williamson' ] ]
```

**An example with an array:**

```
const arr = ['hello', 'john'];

// Object.keys(arr) will give you:
[ '0', '1' ] // note index are returned as strings

// Object.entries(arr) will give you:
[ [ '0', 'hello' ], [ '1', 'john' ] ]
```

**An example with String:**

```
const str = 'I am a String';

// Object.keys(str) will give you:
[
  '0',  '1', '2',  '3',
  '4',  '5', '6',  '7',
  '8',  '9', '10', '11',
  '12'
] // Note index are returned as strings

// Object.entries(str) will give you:
[
  [ '0', 'I' ],  [ '1', ' ' ],
  [ '2', 'a' ],  [ '3', 'm' ],
  [ '4', ' ' ],  [ '5', 'a' ],
  [ '6', ' ' ],  [ '7', 'S' ],
  [ '8', 't' ],  [ '9', 'r' ],
  [ '10', 'i' ], [ '11', 'n' ],
  [ '12', 'g' ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The former returns a list of `[key, values]` while the latter only returns a list of keys.

The former allows you to trivially create a `mapObject` :

```
const mapObject = (obj, proj) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({ ...r, [k]: proj(v) }), {});
```